# Buildozer, How to add external python packages?

Tags: java, android, python, python-2.7, import

I have built a kivy app using Python 2.7. I have used the import statements

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import *
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy import Config
import sqlite3
import webbrowser
from kivy.lang import Builder
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata
from threading import Thread
import requests`
```

In my Buildozer.spec file

```
requirements = kivy,requests,bs4
```

I have set the requirements to use these, as the rest of the packages are inbuilt in Python. I did not specify them. The APK Gets built and I run it on my android phone and the app crashes without any error. I dont understand where the problem lies. If it is my buildozer spec requirements or improper usage of packages.

I have been searching all over the internet , and I have read the Buildozer docs, But I haven't been able to find a good tutorial on how to use Buildozer . I am using it on Linux. Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem. I've narrowed it down to the bs4 library, at the moment i havent got to the bottom of it but i think it is something to do with mixing python 2.7 ans python 3. Anyway the first link is to my (so far) unsolved question.

[Kivy App build with Buildozer. APK crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880264/kivy-app-build-with-buildozer-apk-crash)

The following link is to a set of instructions that may help you find your problem.

**adb install instructions:-**

http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378

**adb logcat fault finding:-**

[adb logcat hangs with "waiting for device" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005509/adb-logcat-hangs-with-waiting-for-device-message)

Hope this helps.