# Kivy App build with Buildozer. APK crash

Tags: python, kivy, android-logcat, ubuntu-16.04, buildozer

I am using Oracle VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16. I have been able to build apk files for a while until my latest build. My program will run and keep its functionality when run with python 2.7 on the same Virtual machine. When i install the .apk file on my Samsung S3 it shows the standard kivy loading screen then crashes after around 20 seconds. PLEASE HELP

I ran the latest build with verabose below is the log file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1XW1ekAndYiT2NrUTRNeHZhVGc

**EDIT**

After researching adb logcat i have been able to find this error. It occurs when "adb logcat" is run on a usb connected device.

```
I/python  (29113):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (29113):    File "/home/paul/Desktop/10/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 11, in <module>
I/python  (29113):    File "/home/paul/Desktop/10/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/bs4/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
I/python  (29113):    File "/home/paul/Desktop/10/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 315, in <module>
I/python  (29113):  ImportError: cannot import name _htmlparser
I/python  (29113): Python for android ended.
```

**EDIT**

Line 11 in main.py is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

I there something obvious im missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turn USB Debuggin mode on in your device and connect your device to your PC and then run `adb logcat`. Run the application on your device and see what is going on in your application and what is the reason of crashing. you could also show us the the `adb logcat` result if you couldn't figure out the reason.

Comment: I have learned alot about fault finding on android. Thank you for your advice Amin.

Comment: @JohnPaul something is wrong with bs4 probably, what python version are you using?